# Selenium vba no such window: window was already closed

Tags: excel, selenium, vba

I have Main Window and Sub Window, when i click on OK button in Sub window, I got the below Error. How to handle this?

Selenium VBA :

```
Dim driver As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Set driver = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

driver.selectWindow ("AIF - Generic Request with Type (rap-alpha-ndc-pr.csc.com)")            'Main Window
aa = driver.WindowHandle   'Main Window
driver.Click "id=WIN_0_603220144"    'Sub Window open here
driver.selectWindow ("Cost Object Search (rap-alpha-ndc-pr.csc.com)") ' Selecting Sub Window to work on this page.
driver.Click "id=WIN_0_603220135" 'Clicking on Sub window and it close automatically.

driver.switchToWindow (aa)  ' it helps to switch to Main Window